# How to block the current task only, without blocking the other tasks on the same thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

Is there a way in C# to wait until a specific task returns or timeout after a specified number of milliseconds, withOUT making all the other tasks running on the same thread be blocked as well ?

Comment: could you provide code you want to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are starting the tasks individually, and not using Parallel.For/ForEach/Invoke, etc. i.e. You are getting a Task object back, then something like this:

```
Task taskIWantToWaitFor = Task.Factory.Start(....);
// Other code
taskIWantToWaitFor.Wait(millisecondsTimeout)
// All other tasks continue in the background
```